# Should I give my Japanese host omiyage/gift when meeting them first or when I'm leaving?

Tags: japan, cultural-awareness, gifts

I'll be visiting Japan soon and I'll be meeting a friend there.

I was wondering if the etiquette there was to give a gift when you first arrive or when you'll be leaving.

When should I give the *omiyage*?

Comment: You - or others following this question - might be interested in the proposed [Japanese culture](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59039/japanese-culture) site on Area51. I'd certainly like to see questions like this there if it makes it to beta.

Comment: Although, arriving from a foreign destination to Japan for a visit, you can still give a gift (and it is still often called omiyage).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**When you meet them.**

*You* may well get "reverse omiyage" from your friend when you're leaving, though!

Answer (score 3):

Definitely arrive with a gift from your home country.  Edibles and tea or coffee are common gifts and widely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You give it as soon as things have settled down and you're at their home. They WILL give you something back when you leave, and the value of their gift to you will depend on the value of the gift you give them. Thus, while it is important to not get something too cheap, it is likewise important to not overdo it either.